# To Show Closedness of a Graph in an Application of Closed Graph Theorem

Tags: functional-analysis

Here's an old exam question I am struggling with:

> Let E be a Banach space and $ (x_n)_{n \in N} \subset E $ such that $
>  \sum_{n=1} ^{\infty} | \langle x_n , x^* \rangle |  < \infty $ for all
>   continuous linear functionals $ x^* \in E^* $.
>
> Show that then there exists a constant $ C < \infty $ such that $$
>  \sum_{n=1} ^{\infty} | \langle x_n , x^* \rangle |  \leq C||x^*|| .$$

What I know is that I should show that the graph of a linear map $ T: E^* \rightarrow l^1 $ is closed and then the continuity of $ T $ would follow from the closed graph theorem.

But the problem here is that I don't have any idea where to start showing closedness of the graph.

Comment: I want to say that the convergence of the sum implies that the graph contains its limit points, but I'm really not sure, hence why commenting instead of answering.

Answer (score 1):

Well, I am not using the Closed graph theorem really but I am using  Banach-Steinhaus theorem, which is a corollary of the Uniform Boundedness Principle. (I think it is possible to deduce each of them using the other.)

As you said we will define a continuous map from $E^* \to \ell ^1$.

Define $T_{k} : E^* \to \ell ^1$ by $T_k(x^*) = (x^*(x_1) , \ldots, x^*(x_k), 0,0 \ldots ) $. It is easy to see that each $T_k$ is linear.

We prove it is bounded. Indeed,

$||T_k(x^*)||_{\ell ^1} = \sum_{i=1}^{k}  |x^*(x_i)| \le \sum_{i=1}^{k} ||x^*|| ||x_i|| = \left( \sum_{i=1}^{k} ||x_i|| \right) ||x^*||$.

Now, by your hypothesis, $T_k(x^*)$ converges as $k \to \infty$ for each $x^* \in E^*$.

Therefore, by BST, $T(x^*) := \lim _{k \to \infty} T_k(x^*)$ is a bounded linear operator.

This gives you the conclusion.

Comment: I believe that the prove works for any normed linear speace $E$ not just Banach.